# Google login is blocked

Tags: support, login

I have my stack overflow account in which I login via Google account(My one and only login for stack overflow). Now the problem is that in my company they have blocked  google account so that I am not able to login in my stack overflow account. How can I login into my stack overflow account again??

Comment: I fear you will have to start new account, then ask for a merge.

Comment: merge?? what is that?? I mean how to achieve it please explain I have almost 3k reputation in my account and I want to continue with my SO account @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Neel - See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/187824)

Comment: @ShadowWizard he says his company blocks this, so he *should* be able to fix it by going elsewhere (home, Starbucks, phone, whatever), adding a second OpenID that his company doesn't block, and then using that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I was under the impression the company owns the account (my company is using gmail) and blocked it, i.e. no access to the account anywhere. Might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than create a new account and ask for a merge, login into your account from a **non-work** computer and add a new login - one that isn't blocked by your employer.

Then when you next login from work use that ID and you should be able to access your account.

Comment: yes I have done the same but facing problem see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234140/not-able-to-add-new-login

Comment: @Neel - that looks like a problem with LiveJournal. Is there another login you can add to try. There's no limit (I've found) to the number of logins you can add to your SE account.