# Not able to add a new login

Tags: support, bug, openid

This question is a forward story of the question *[Google login is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234134/google-login-is-blocked)*.

I have created a LiveJournal account so that I can log into Stack Overflow through it as it's not banned in our company. And I tried to add a login, but it says *No OpenID end point found* even though I have provided a valid user name as shown below.

[image: A screenshot of the failed attempt]

[image: Another screenshot]

And my Livejournal account:

[image: Screenshot of a Livejournal account]

[image: Another screenshot of the Livejournal account]

Comment: I've found LiveJournal to be kind of flaky for this.  (Ok, kind of flaky in general, but I've been there forever so don't want to move.)  A similar non-flaky site is DreamWidth; I've used their OpenID without problems.

Comment: I don't even know what is livejournal I have made account account just to use it for SO and now its working @MonicaCellio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it again after some time, and it worked as expected. I gave the username in the textbox, and it worked!!

Comment: Weird, so maybe it was caching on their side.